# Is something wrong with my authentication controller when assigning the user variable?

Tags: sequelize.js, vuejs3

I am working to build a login, I have been using postman to help verify each post and get and as I got to my first post route, there seems to be an issue with my User model. at first I had an issue with postman in that my req.body was blank but looked up that I needed to specify what kind of information I was passing through given the options available in postman (x-www-form-urlencoded). After getting that out of the way, I keep getting an error to the tune of (TypeError: User.create is not a function). Is there an issue with my models? or maybe it's the way I am using sequelize?

This is my User Model:

```
`const { DataTypes, sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {

  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  return User;
};`
```

And this is my Authentication Controller:

```
`const { sequelize } = require('../models');
const User = require('../models/User.js');
console.log(User)


module.exports = {
     async register(req, res) {
      try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;
        const user =  await User.create({name, email, password});  
        await user.save();
        res.send(user.toJSON());
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({
          error: `there is an issue: ${err}`,
        });
      }
    },
  };`
```

All I need is for the create function to operate but it seems to not work.